# Split the number and keep one number after the dot

Tags: php, split, explode

I have following string: `$string = "10x1.12A"` and I wanted result to be: `10x1.1` . I have different combinations at the end but I just wanted to get one number after the dot and remove everything after that.

Comment: Based on your follow up questions under the accepted answer, we don't have a sufficient [mcve].  Changing the requirements after people answer is rude, frustrating and a waste of contributor time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest using `preg_match_all` with the regex pattern `^.*?\.\d`:

```
$string = "10x1.12A";
preg_match_all ("/^.*?\.\d/", $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0];
```

This prints:

```
10x1.1
```

There is also possibly a `preg_replace` way of doing this:

```
$string = "10x1.12A";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=\.\d).*$/", "", $string);
echo $output;
```

This approach strips off everything which appears after the dot-number.  Note that I assume here that there would be only one dot.

Comment: I need one number after the dot.. It don't want to disappear everything after the dot

Comment: Um...my answers _are_ leaving one number after the dot.

Comment: I got one more condition :( What if I have AB10x1.12A and I wanted to show 10x1.1 only?

Comment: Use: `preg_match_all ("/\d+.*?\.\d/", "AB10x1.12A", $matches);`

Comment: I have one another scenario where I have 'AB10 10x1.12A' and I wanted to show 10x1.1

Comment: How fun is it when the asker keeps changing the question requirements, Tim?!?  (Just quietly, `preg_match_all()` is not a choice I would make)

Comment: For the record, I hate that as much as you, and sometimes I downvote and delete my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "10x1.12A" ;
$dotpos = strpos($string, '.'); // find the position of the first dot in the string
$result = substr($string, 0, $dotpos+2); // take the string from the start to the digit after the first dot
echo $result // 10x1.1
```